# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, mern

I am getting an Error while giving store value in index.js

Store.js

```
import { legacy_createStore as createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from 'react-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import { productReducer } from "./reducers/productReducer";

const reducer = combineReducers({
    products:productReducer,
});
let initialState = {};
const middleware = [thunk];
const  store = createStore(reducer,  initialState, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)));

export default store;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);
```

I am expecting that something is missing in script.js file

Comment: Two questions: 1) Are you actually using any JS classes in your code anywhere? 2) You're using a very outdated style of Redux code (as shown by the use of `legacy_createStore`). Is there a reason why you're not using our official Redux Toolkit package to set up the store and write the Redux logic? See https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today and https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-2-app-structure for examples.

Comment: I got it , Actually I was using react-thunk node package but its redux-thunk

Comment: Thank You! for your time and valuable feedback